# Microfocus Net Express COBOL, Replace PERFORM PARA with actual code

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I'm using Net Express 5.1. I want to know if it is possible to replace `PERFORM PARA` with the actual paragraph code. In the `.lst` file, we get all the `COPY` statements expanded and I want the same for `PERFORM` statement.

If yes please tell me what are the compiler options I need to set.

Comment: You have some choices: 1) change or get a better analyser that doesn't require this (what languages do you know that would do this for you?); 2) write some code to do the "expansion" yourself; 3) manually achieve it; 4) do something else. Depending on how your PERFORMs are formed, number 2) is straightforward, or not. How about adding a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is **very** unlikely that there is a compiler option for this.
If you need it: move the section into a copybook and use this everywhere.

BTW: What are the reasons you want to do so? There may be a better option to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: There are so many paragraphs. so it is not possible to manually copy all the paragraphs into copybooks. Please tell me if there is any way to get the paragraphs in to separate copybooks.  I need the expanded file this way for some analysis.

Comment: A good analysis tool would do the work itself.
If the tool comes from you just generate the listings and look for `PERFORM`, then insert the next paragraph with the name (if it is a paragraph) or the complete section.

If you look for a tool enabling you to do analysis and you're familiar with Java I suggest to try [Koopa](https://sourceforge.net/p/koopa/).